# How to validate file size to upload php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

I'm newby with php + mysql and i have this script to upload a file to a server and insert the data to a database. All works fine except that I don't know how to limit the file size to 3MB. Here is the code:

```
// limit file types
$valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp' , 'pdf' , 'doc' , 'ppt'); // valid extensions
$path = 'uploads/'; // upload directory

if(!empty($_POST['name']) || !empty($_POST['email']) || $_FILES['image'])
{
$img = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

// get uploaded file extension
$ext = strtolower(pathinfo($img, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

// rename file to prevent rewrite existing files
$final_image = rand(1000,1000000).$img;

// check's valid format
if(in_array($ext, $valid_extensions)) 
{ 
$path = $path.strtolower($final_image); 

if(move_uploaded_file($tmp,$path)) 
{
echo "File uploaded succesfully";
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

//include database configuration file
include_once 'db.php';

//insert form data in the database
$insert = $db->query("INSERT uploading (name,email,file_name) VALUES ('".$name."','".$email."','".$path."')");

}
} 
else 
{
echo 'File not uploaded, try again';
}
}
```

I'll appreciatte any help.

Comment: You can use $_FILES['image']['size'] or filesize($path).

Answer (score 0):

First, fetch file size in KB as:

```
$fileSize = $_FILES['image']['size'];
```

Then you can convert bytes into MBs as:

`$fileSizeInMB = ($fileSize)/(1024*1024)`;

Then you can have a check if this $fileSizeInMB is greater than 3 or not.

Answer (score 0):

you can modify the php.ini file to set a maximum file size that you will allow to upload.

upload_max_filesize = 40M

or you can set it in your script a

```
$fileSize = $_FILES['image']['size'];
```

than use a if statement

```
if ($fileSize < 3000000) {
            echo "this image cannot be uploaded";
        }
```

Inserted in your script.

```
   <?php


    $valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp' , 'pdf' , 'doc' , 'ppt'); // valid extensions
    $path = 'uploads/'; // upload directory

    if(!empty($_POST['name']) || !empty($_POST['email']) || $_FILES['image'] )
    {


    $img = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['image']['size']

    // get uploaded file extension
    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($img, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

    // rename file to prevent rewrite existing files
    $final_image = rand(1000,1000000).$img;



    // check's valid format
    if(in_array($ext, $valid_extensions))
    {
    $path = $path.strtolower($final_image);

// if condition to make sure filesize is less than 3000000 bytes, 3MB
    if($fileSize < 3000000){ //php uses bytes so 3000000 is 3MB 


    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp,$path))
    {
    echo "File uploaded succesfully";
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    //include database configuration file
    include_once 'db.php';

    //insert form data in the database
    $insert = $db->query("INSERT uploading (name,email,file_name) VALUES ('".$name."','".$email."','".$path."')");
    }
    } else {

    echo 'Cannot upload file too large' ;
    }
    }

    else
    {
    echo 'File not uploaded, try again';
    }
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: I don't know where to put it in the script, can you put an example please?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Just two things:

    $fileSize = $_FILES['image']['size'];

Comment: Sorry for the previeous comment...

Just two things:

1. You forgot a semicolon at the end of $filesize

    $fileSize = $_FILES['image']['size'];

2. When uploading files grater than 6MB, the error message doesn't appear. The message shows only for files from 3MB to 6MB. I've modified to 40MB the upload_max_filesize = 40M in php.ini but the message still doesn't appears. What can i do?

Comment: I just put a value in upload_max_filesize= 40M as a example, you need to set it to your user specific settings, so if that setting it 3MB that it will be upload_max_filesize = 3M

Answer (score 0):

The $_FILES is a global variable in PHP and an array element and contains the key named

`size`,
this is the size of the file which you are trying to upload, you can add any validations on this key element.

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php